# Google Cloud Speech-to-Text doesn't transcribe streamed audio correctly on some iDevices

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition

I've implemented the Google Cloud Speech to Text API using realtime streamed audio for the past few weeks. While initially everything looked really well, I've been testing the product on some more devices lately and have found some real weird irregularities when it comes to some iDevices.
First of all, here are the relevant code pieces:

**Frontend (React Component)**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.audio = props.audio;
  this.socket = new SocketClient();
  this.bufferSize = 2048;
}

/**
* Initializes the users microphone and the audio stream.
*
* @return {void}
*/
startAudioStream = async () => {
  const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  this.audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  this.processor = this.audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(this.bufferSize, 1, 1);
  this.processor.connect(this.audioCtx.destination);
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
  /* Debug through instant playback:
  this.audio.srcObject = stream;
  this.audio.play();
  return; */

  this.globalStream = stream;
  this.audioCtx.resume();
  this.input = this.audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  this.input.connect(this.processor);

  this.processor.onaudioprocess = (e) => {
    this.microphoneProcess(e);
  };
  this.setState({ streaming: true });
}

/**
 * Processes microphone input and passes it to the server via the open socket connection.
 *
 * @param {AudioProcessingEvent} e
 * @return {void}
 */
microphoneProcess = (e) => {
  const { speaking, askingForConfirmation, askingForErrorConfirmation } = this.state;
  const left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  const left16 = Helpers.downsampleBuffer(left, 44100, 16000);
  if (speaking === false) {
    this.socket.emit('stream', {
      audio: left16,
      context: askingForConfirmation || askingForErrorConfirmation ? 'zip_code_yes_no' : 'zip_code',
      speechContext: askingForConfirmation || askingForErrorConfirmation ? ['ja', 'nein', 'ne', 'nö', 'falsch', 'neu', 'korrektur', 'korrigieren', 'stopp', 'halt', 'neu'] : ['$OPERAND'],
    });
  }
}
```

**Helpers (DownsampleBuffer)**

```
/**
 * Downsamples a given audio buffer from sampleRate to outSampleRate.
 * @param {Array} buffer The audio buffer to downsample.
 * @param {number} sampleRate The original sample rate.
 * @param {number} outSampleRate The new sample rate.
 * @return {Array} The downsampled audio buffer.
 */
static downsampleBuffer(buffer, sampleRate, outSampleRate) {
  if (outSampleRate === sampleRate) {
    return buffer;
  }
  if (outSampleRate > sampleRate) {
    throw new Error('Downsampling rate show be smaller than original sample rate');
  }
  const sampleRateRatio = sampleRate / outSampleRate;
  const newLength = Math.round(buffer.length / sampleRateRatio);
  const result = new Int16Array(newLength);
  let offsetResult = 0;
  let offsetBuffer = 0;
  while (offsetResult < result.length) {
    const nextOffsetBuffer = Math.round((offsetResult + 1) * sampleRateRatio);
    let accum = 0;
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = offsetBuffer; i < nextOffsetBuffer && i < buffer.length; i++) {
      accum += buffer[i];
      count++;
    }

    result[offsetResult] = Math.min(1, accum / count) * 0x7FFF;
    offsetResult++;
    offsetBuffer = nextOffsetBuffer;
  }
  return result.buffer;
}
```

**Backend (Socket Server)**

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  logger.debug('New client connected');
  const speechClient = new SpeechService(socket);

  socket.on('stream', (data) => {
    const audioData = data.audio;
    const context = data.context;
    const speechContext = data.speechContext;
    speechClient.transcribe(audioData, context, speechContext);
  });
});
```

**Backend (Speech Client / Transcribe Function where data is sent to GCloud)**

```
async transcribe(data, context, speechContext, isFile = false) {
  if (!this.recognizeStream) {
    logger.debug('Initiating new Google Cloud Speech client...');
    let waitingForMoreData = false;
    // Create new stream to the Google Speech client
    this.recognizeStream = this.speechClient
      .streamingRecognize({
        config: {
          encoding: 'LINEAR16',
          sampleRateHertz: 16000,
          languageCode: 'de-DE',
          speechContexts: speechContext ? [{ phrases: speechContext }] : undefined,
        },
        interimResults: false,
        singleUtterance: true,
      })
      .on('error', (error) => {
        if (error.code === 11) {
          this.recognizeStream.destroy();
          this.recognizeStream = null;
          return;
        }
        this.socket.emit('error');
        this.recognizeStream.destroy();
        this.recognizeStream = null;
        logger.error(`Received error from Google Cloud Speech client: ${error.message}`);
      })
      .on('data', async (gdata) => {
        if ((!gdata.results || !gdata.results[0]) && gdata.speechEventType === 'END_OF_SINGLE_UTTERANCE') {
          logger.debug('Received END_OF_SINGLE_UTTERANCE - waiting 300ms for more data before restarting stream');
          waitingForMoreData = true;
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (waitingForMoreData === true) {
              // User was silent for too long - restart stream
              this.recognizeStream.destroy();
              this.recognizeStream = null;
            }
          }, 300);
          return;
        }
        waitingForMoreData = false;
        const transcription = gdata.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
        logger.debug(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);

        // Emit transcription and MP3 file of answer
        this.socket.emit('transcription', transcription);
        const filename = await ttsClient.getAnswerFromTranscription(transcription, 'fairy', context); // TODO-Final: Dynamic character
        if (filename !== null) this.socket.emit('speech', `${config.publicScheme}://${config.publicHost}:${config.publicPort}/${filename}`);

        // Restart stream
        if (this.recognizeStream) this.recognizeStream.destroy();
        this.recognizeStream = null;
      });
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename
  if (isFile === true) fs.createReadStream(data).pipe(this.recognizeStream);
  else this.recognizeStream.write(data);
}
```

Now, the behavior varies heavily throughout my tested devices. I've originally developed on an iMac 2017 using Google Chrome as a browser. Works like a charm. Then, tested on an iPhone 11 Pro and iPad Air 4, both on Safari and as a full-screen web app. Again, works like a charm.

Afterwards I've tried with an iPad Pro 12.9" 2017. **Suddenly, Google Cloud sometimes doesn't return a transcription at all, some other times it returns stuff which, only using very much fantasy, sounds like the actually spoken text.** Same behavior on an iPad 5 and an iPhone 6 Plus.

I don't really know where to go from here. What I've read up on so far at least is that with the iPhone 6s (no idea about iPads unfortunately) the hardware sample rate was changed from 44.1khz to 48khz. So I thought, this might be it, played around with the sample rates everywhere in the code, no success. Also, I've noticed that my iMac with Google Chrome also runs on 44.1khz like the "old" iPads where transcription doesn't work. Likewise, the new iPads run on 48khz - and here everything works fine. So this can't be it.

What I've noticed as well: When I connect some AirPods to the "broken" devices and use them as audio input, everything works again. **So this must have something to do with processing of the internal microphone of those devices.** I just don't know what exactly.

Could anyone lead me to the right direction? What has changed between these device generations in regards to audio and the microphone?

**Update 1**: I've now implemented a quick function which writes the streamed PCM data from the frontend to a file in the backend using node-wav. I think, I'm getting closer now - on the devices, where the speech recognition goes nuts, I sound like a chipmunk (extremely high-pitched). I've also noticed that the binary audio data is flowing in way slower than on the devices where everything is working fine. So this probably has to do with sample/bit rate, encoding or something. Unfortunately I'm not an audio expert, so not sure what to do next.

**Update 2**: After a lot of trial end error, I've found that if I set the sample rate to about 9500 to 10000 in the Google Cloud `RecognizeConfig`, everything works. When I set this as the sample rate for the node-wav file output, it sounds *okay* as well. If I reset the "outgoing" sample rate to GCloud to 16000 again and downsample the audio input to about 25000 instead of 16000 in the frontend from 44100 (see "Frontend (React Component)" in the "microphoneProcess" function), it works as well. So there seems to be some kind of ~0.6 factor in sample rate differences. However, I still don't know where this behavior is coming from: Both Chrome on the working iMac and Safari on the "broken" iPads have a `audioContext.sampleRate` of 44100. Therefore, when I downsample them to 16000 in the code, I'd suppose both should work, whereas only the iMac works. It seems like the iPad is working with a different sample rate internally?

Answer (score 1):

After a ton of trial and error, I've found the problem (and the solution).
It seems like "older" iDevice models - like the 2017 iPad Pro - have some weird peculiarity of automatically adjusting the microphone sample rate to the rate of played audio. Even though the hardware sample rate of those devices is set to 44.1khz, as soon as some audio is played, the rate changes. This can be observed through something like this:

```
const audioCtx = new webkitAudioContext();
console.log(`Current sample rate: ${audioCtx.sampleRate}`); // 44100
const audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'some_audio.mp3';
await audio.play();
console.log(`Current sample rate: ${audioCtx.sampleRate}`); // Sample rate of the played audio
```

In my case I've played some synthesized speech from Google Text-to-Speech before opening the speech transcription socket. Those sound files have a sample rate of 24khz - exactly the sample rate Google Cloud received my audio input in.

The solution therefore was - something I should have done anyways - to downsample everything to 16khz (see my helper function in the question), but not from hard-coded 44.1khz, rather from the current sample rate of the audio context. So I've changed my `microphoneProcess()` function like this:

```
const left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
const left16 = Helpers.downsampleBuffer(left, this.audioCtx.sampleRate, 16000);
```

**Conclusion**: Do not trust Safari with the sample rate on page load. It might change.